# library missing cannot find -lbz2 in arch

Tags: c++, linker, linker-errors, libraries, archlinux

while building statically an error

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lbz2
```

I am currently using arch linux. earlier I used ubuntu there I used

```
 sudo apt-get install libbz2-dev
```

I am new to arch and dont know which library to install and how to find such libraries in future.

Maybe this info be useful:

```
archlinux:~$ ls /usr/lib/ | grep bz2
libbz2.so
libbz2.so.1
libbz2.so.1.0
libbz2.so.1.0.6

archlinux:~$ locate libbz2
/usr/lib/libbz2.so
/usr/lib/libbz2.so.1
/usr/lib/libbz2.so.1.0
/usr/lib/libbz2.so.1.0.6
/usr/lib32/libbz2.so
/usr/lib32/libbz2.so.1
/usr/lib32/libbz2.so.1.0
/usr/lib32/libbz2.so.1.0.6
```

I can see that libbz2.a file is missing how to get that?

Comment: You need to install `bzip2` from source

Comment: @Mohit I have installed that using sudo pacman -S bzip2 isn't that sufficient

Comment: If that provides header files and link libraries than that is sufficient

Comment: @Mohit can you please have a look on the edits. I have edited and added output of locate command. I think link libraries are installed

Comment: You need `libbz2.a` when linking statically, not a `.so`. As it appears there is no `libbz2-static` package you'll need to compile and build it yourself from source.

Comment: @TypeIA I have compiled the source and I got the file libbz2.a , I moved it to /usr/lib and also ran chmod +x libbz2.a , still m not getting it in `locate libbz2`

Comment: `locate` has nothing to do with whether you can compile it (that said, you probably need to run `updatedb` to reindex your filesystem before it shows up in `locate`). If `libbz2.a` is available in a standard link path (or a path you give the linker with `-L`) it should compile fine.

Comment: And it should not be marked executable; you can (and should) chmod -x it.